# Action delegate defined with 1 in parameter used with 2 in parameters

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

Given these definitions:

```
public ICommand OkCommand { get; set; }

public ModelCommand(Action<object> execute)

public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
```

This code compiles:

```
this.OkCommand = new ModelCommand(x => this.Ok(this, new EventArgs()));

this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand<ThisType>(x => this.Ok(this, new EventArgs()));

this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand<EventArgs>(x => this.Ok(this, new EventArgs()));
```

However I am confused as why this compiles and whether I understand it correctly.
In both case the `Action` method has 1 `in` parameter, while the function `this.Ok` has 2.
How are the parameters handled by the `Action` delegate, which parameter does it receive and why?

Comment: The left-hand side of the `=>` lambda arrow contains `(object x)`, and `(ThisType x)` and `(EventArgs x)`, respectively. That is one parameter. The syntax `(x)` or even `x` is just a short-hand. Whatever happens in the expression on the right is irrelevant. Had the left-hand side been `(x, y)` for example, that would be two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write an anonymous delegate or a lambda expression, you can use any member from the current scope, not only the arguments passed to the method. The compiler creates a *closure* that captures everything necessary for the lambda to execute.

So your code is roughly translated to something like:

```
private class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        var closure = new <>c__DisplayClass1 { _this = this };
        OkCommand = new ModelCommand(new Action<object>(closure.b__0));
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1
    {
        public MyClass _this;

        public void b__0(object o)
        {
            return _this.Ok(_this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

The `b__0` method matches the `Action<object>` signature, and the generated class contains all the fields you referenced in the lambda.

Because of this behavior, closures *extend the scope* of the fields captured within them, so you must be aware where you send the lambda to or you may experience unwanted memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

But your constructors **do take** only one parameter - it is called `x`. You can translate:

```
RelayCommand<EventArgs>(x => this.Ok(this, new EventArgs()));
```

into:

```
RelayCommand<EventArgs>(delegate(EventArgs x)
{
    this.Ok(this, new EventArgs());
});
```

or even:

```
RelayCommand<EventArgs>(SomeTemporaryDelegate);

public void SomeTemporaryDelegate(EventArgs x)
{
    this.Ok(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

which maybe will clarify the things. You are simply not using `x` inside delegate, using external variables as a parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Action` takes a parameter, which in this case in the command parameter passed into the command when it executes. So, in the case of:

```
this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand<EventArgs>(x => this.Ok(this, new EventArgs()));
```

`x` will be an `EventArgs` instance. The action doesn't do anything with the parameter and just calls straight down to `Ok`, although it could also have been written as:

```
this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand<EventArgs>(x => this.Ok(this, x));
```

as it looks like `Ok` takes as `EventArgs` as it's second parameter

It's the same for:

```
this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand<ThisType>(x => this.Ok(this, new EventArgs()));
```

It takes a `ThisType` commanand parameter and does nothing with it.

If you're using the standard `RelayCommand` class then there's an non-generic version that just takes a no-argument `Action`, which would allow you to write:

```
this.OkCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.Ok(this, x));
```

Which probably is clearer, as it makes clear you're not interested in the command parameter.

Comment: I used your last version, which looks the most clear to me (with x replaced by new EventArgs().

Answer (score 1):

```
this.OkCommand = new ModelCommand(x => this.Ok(this, new EventArgs()));
```

In this case, when you invoke `this.OkCommand();`:

- the `ModelCommand` delegate will be called, which:
- will evaluate its expression, which
- will evaluate the `Ok` call contained within the expression, which
- will evaluate the parameters contained within the call, which
- will evaluate `this`, which is a "closure" (i.e., a variable that was captured), as the enclosing object and `new EventArgs()`.

tl;dr: When you invoke `OkCommand`, you don't call `Ok` directly. Instead, `OkCommand` will invoke `RelayCommand`, which has all the information necessary to properly call `Ok`.